# Add button greyed out at IOS developer program page

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am using IOS university program and I follow the steps to debug the apps in Iphone according to the tutorial in mobiletuts but I am stuck at the step "Create App ID" after the certificate because the Add button has greyed out. Any idea what happened?

[image]

Comment: Try the developer portal to create app id's.

Comment: Did you mean Xcode? Or maybe you can send me the link?
I already in the IOS dev program> certificates> identifier

Comment: Mea culpa, i mistook your screenshot for an XCode screenshot. I now see that it is a screenshot from the web. If the button to create an App ID is disabled, check if your developers license is still valid.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem? I'm having the same one and I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and is related to member level permissions.  My permission level for the team was set to "Member" instead of "Admin".  Once this was changed to Admin by the Team Agent, I had the ability to add App IDs.

The link below provides the list of team privileges based on membership level.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: I have been assigned a 'Developer' role and yet I am not able to add devices or create/edit a provisioning profile. Any help?!

Comment: Same issue for me did you find the solution?